# How to use in built keyboard FN functionality as default

Tags: keyboard

My laptop's in built keyboard and my USB keyboard both have FN key but they work differently. For example, when I press Fn+F5 in built-in keyboard it's reduces screen brightness but same combination in my external keyboard functions to play previous song.
I prefer my in-built keyboard. So, How can I get this using my external keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the keyboard has some sort of key remapping tool, the only way is to use autohotkey. The function keys are set by the keyboard not by the computer. What you could do is write a short script the decreases the screen brightness when It detects the  previous song button.